# Can I cut a fee using multicall on Uniswap V3?

Tags: erc-20, uniswap, uniswapv3, erc-20-approve, multicall

I developed my own frontend for Uniswap V3, and I was asking myself if I could cut a small fee of the input token using multicall.

Basically, I would calculate what 2 percent of the input token would be and subtract that from the input amount, then I would create an Erc20 transferFrom, with src being the frontend user, destination me, and amount being 2% of the input tokens.

But when I try to do that with Multicall I get the error "STF".

Now I'm asking myself, is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Comment: Does it work without multicall? STF is "Safe Transfer From", caused by missing approval or not enough tokens, it may not be related to multicall itself.